# How write SQL count columns group by?

Tags: sql, count

I have table

```
UserName   Readed
HuynhNH    True 
HuynhNH    False    
HuynhNH    True 
HaiNV      False    
HaiNV      True 
QuyetM     False
```

And get the result:

```
UserName  readed
HuynhNH   2     
HaiNV     1 
QuyetM    0
```

How shall I to write the sql?thanks support

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN reader = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` -- this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Try-

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Readed = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: glad to see you made it,:).

Comment: Thanks you, I have been successful

select UserName, SUM(CASE WHEN Readed = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as t
from TABLE
group by UserName

Answer (score 0):

It depends by your Database, is it Mysql?

You could as simple do:

```
select username,
       sum(readed)
from t
group by username;
```

Test data:

```
create table t (
  username char(20),
  readed boolean
  );

insert into t values('HuynhNH',true);
insert into t values('HuynhNH',false);
insert into t values('HuynhNH',true);
insert into t values('HaiNV',false);
insert into t values('HaiNV',true);
insert into t values('QuyetM',false);

insert into t values('MrSimpleMind',true);
insert into t values('MrSimpleMind',false);
```

See SQLFiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc217/4

Comment: Thanks you, I have been successful select UserName, SUM(CASE WHEN Readed = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as t from TABLE group by UserName